# How do I wake the boss at the top of the Tower of Nod?

Tags: dragon-quest-9

There doesn't seem to be any way in game to do it.  I've tried various abilities (like Whistle) and the party tricks, but none seem to work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this looks to be impossible in the current state of the game.  There will be a DLC that you can buy sometime in the near future that will allow you to continue on.

Comment: FWIW, the DLC for DQ IX thus far has been free.  I don't think that a mechanism to collect payment exists.

Answer (score 4):

You can now download quest #162 from DQVC.  There is no cost for this.  As part of this quest, you'll be able to wake up this boss.

There are some prerequisites for this quest.  You must finish these other quests (also from DLC) in order:  159, 160, 161.